# Capture response on failed/401 Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell

How do I capture the output when Invoke-WebRequest hits a 500, 401, 403, etc.? When the call is successful, it stores the result in the `$Response` variable, but if I hit a 401 it throws the error but doesn't store the response.

```
$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method HEAD -Uri 'https://site.contoso.com'
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At line:1 char:13
+ $Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method HEAD -Uri 'https://site.contoso.com' -Erro ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

The `$Response` variable remains null, however the endpoint is returning the 401 Unauthorized *and* headers, it's just not being captured by PowerShell since it is treating it as an exception. Piping it through Fiddler confirms this.

Creating a request using `[System.Net.WebRequest]` has the same result when I execute `$Response = $WebRequest.GetResponse()`.

Here's my `$PSVersionTable`.

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                           
----                           -----                                                                                                           
PSVersion                      4.0                                                                                                             
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                             
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                         
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.36373                                                                                                 
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406                                                                                                  
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}                                                                                            
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually an [open issue on the PowerShell project on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2193), it might be resolved some day though.

For now, here is how we tend to work around that.

First, load this function into memory.

```
function Failure {
$global:helpme = $body
$global:helpmoref = $moref
$global:result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
$global:reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($global:result)
$global:responseBody = $global:reader.ReadToEnd();
Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "Status: A system exception was caught."
Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red $global:responsebody
Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "The request body has been saved to `$global:helpme"
break
}
```

Then, wrap your WebRequests like this.

```
try
{
    $Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method HEAD -Uri 'https://site.contoso.com'
}
catch
{
    Failure
}
```

The cool thing about this approach is that it writes *Globally Scoped Variables*, and they'll persist after your function exits.  When you do encounter an error, just poke around inside `$global:result` or `$global:responsebody` for the full error.

This is a must-have when writing modules based on RPC or REST endpoints.

Credit for this [technique goes to Steve Wahl.](http://wahlnetwork.com/2015/02/19/using-try-catch-powershells-invoke-webrequest/)

Comment: Thank you -- this way is far more intuitive and flexible than what I came up with.

Comment: Cool, happy you like it. As a bonus, if you change your function to use $body or store the header as $moref, you will get global variables of those too, for troubleshooting. That function really is helpful.

Comment: Thanks -- for this scenario I was writing a script that *expects* a 401 but I need to extract the headers.

Comment: I can't see anything in the $body variable

Comment: fix has been committed more than 1.5 year ago but problem still exists...

Comment: I believe the fix went to PowerShell 6.0, if you're still on PowerShell 5.0 or 5.1, you won't get that code.

Answer (score 4):

I found that you can capture the Response within a try/catch block.

```
try
{
    $Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method HEAD -Uri 'https://site.contoso.com'
}
catch
{
    $Failure = $_.Exception.Response
}
```

However, this only works if you trap it and look at the Response at the time of running it. You cannot retrieve the Response data from the $Error variable.

Answer (score 2):

Found another response on https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2193 thanks to abhinavsingh003 !

```
Try {
     $WebRequestResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Headers $Headers -Body $BodyJSON -Method $Method -ContentType $ContentType -SkipCertificateCheck
     Write-Host $WebRequestResult
} Catch {
    if($_.ErrorDetails.Message) {
        "----WebResponseError----"
        Write-Host $_.ErrorDetails.Message;
    } else {
        #UsualException
        $_
    }
}
```

You may find a correct Invoke-RestMethod/Invoke-WebRequest from i9shankar's
Powershell BitBucket project :
https://github.com/i9shankar/ps-bitbucket/blob/88edaf469014da16179bb7b215f3fbad04bf2373/Private/Invoke-BitBucketWebRequest.ps1

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me a lot while parsing a DevOps API error response.